# Multiple ajax callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to make a few ajax calls and only when they're all done move on. I've had a look at jQuery's $when().then() but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
$.when(
   getFriends()
).done(function( friends ){
    console.log( friends );
});
```

getFriends then calls another method which makes the ajax request and returns the data, and that's where I think the problem lies.

```
getFriends: function()
{
   apiRequest( 'GET', 'friends', null,
        function( data ){
            return data;
        },

        function( error )
        {
            console.log( error );
        }
    );
}
```

The apiRequest method just takes all the data, adds a few required fields for going off to the server then returns the data. This part is working fine. It's just the whole making getFriends let someone else know when it's done.

```
apiRequest: function( method, endpoint, data, success, error )
{
    var endpoint = config.api_base_url + endpoint;
    var ajax_options = {
        type: method,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        error: error
    };

    if( auth_token = getAuthToken() )
    {
        ajax_options.beforeSend = function( request )
        {
            request.setRequestHeader( 'X-Auth-Token', auth_token );
        };
    }

    $.ajax( endpoint, ajax_options );
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return` the promise that `$.ajax()` yields, you [cannot `return` from the success handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call). Then return a promise from `getFriends` as well:

```
getFriends: function() {
    return apiRequest('GET', 'friends', null).fail(function(error) {
//  ^^^^^^
        console.log(error);
    }); // modified by the fail handler
},
apiRequest: function(method, endpoint, data) {
    var ajax_options = {
        url: config.api_base_url + endpoint,
        type: method,
        data: data
    };
    var auth_token = getAuthToken();
//  ^^^ missing var
    if (auth_token)
        ajax_options.beforeSend = function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader('X-Auth-Token', auth_token);
        };

    return $.ajax(ajax_options);
//  ^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Is there another way I can do it though, make getFriends return it's own promise or something?

Comment: I know I can do that from the apiRequest method but what I'm looking for is a way to do the same sort of thing from getFriends.

Comment: Yes, of course you can transform the promise to a new one (with [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) or one of the [other promise methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)). But at first, you need to `return` the `$.ajax()` promise from `apiRequest()` so that you can consume it in `getFriends`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I can't modify apiRequest like that. It has to be able to work with the callbacks.

Comment: Of course you can leave the `success, error` parameters in the function as optional, but you really should `return` the promise that `$.ajax()` already creates for you. [You can implement an anti-pattern as well if you need to](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern), check [`$.Deferred` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if 'Promises' would be of any interest to you on this?[MDN - Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)